# error C2248: strange error when I use thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I get the following errors

> Error 2   error C2248: 'std::thread::thread' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class
>   'std::thread' c:\dropbox\prog\c++\ttest\ttest\main.cpp    11  1   ttest
>
> Error 1   error C2248: 'std::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class
>   'std::mutex'  c:\dropbox\prog\c++\ttest\ttest\main.cpp    11  1   ttest

my code

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct Serverbas
{
    mutex mut;
    thread t;
};

struct LoginServer : Serverbas
{
    void start()
    {
       t = thread(&LoginServer::run, *this);
    }
    void run() {}
};

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t = thread( &LoginServer::run, *this);
```

That first argument to the member function `run` (implicit in direct calls) should be the `this` pointer, i.e. just `this`. Don't dereference it.

When you dereference it all hell breaks loose because your `std::thread` and `std::mutex` members prevent objects of your class type from being copyable — the copy constructors of these member objects are `private`/`delete`d and *that* is the error you are seeing.

So:

```
t = thread(&LoginServer::run, this);
```

Comment: @NikBougalis: It's the first argument _through_ `std::thread` to the `LoginServer::run` function, but I see your point.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line here:

```
t = thread( &LoginServer::run, *this);
```

By dereferencing this, you are telling the compiler that you want to pass a copy of this object to the thread function.  But your class isn't copy constructible because it contains a std::mutex and std::thread (neither of which is copy constructible).  The errors you're getting are because of the inaccessible copy constructors for those two classes.

To fix it, don't dereference the object.  The code will probably be clearer if you use a lambda anyway, like so:

```
t = thread([this] { run(); });
```